# JavaScript: Check if all arrays contain same value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have the following array

```
// Exmaple
[
   ['morning', 'afternoon'],
   ['morning'],
   ['morning', 'afternoon'],
   ['morning', 'afternoon'],
   ['morning']
]
```

I may have the same one but with afternoon in every array.
I need to check if a given value exists in all arrays, for example if I check for **'morning'** it should return `true`, but if I check for **'afternoon'** it should return `false` because in the example array above not all of them have **'afternoon'**

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  array.every(day => day.includes("morning")) // true
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.every()` and `.includes()` methods:

```js
let data = [
   ['morning', 'afternoon'],
   ['morning'],
   ['morning', 'afternoon'],
   ['morning', 'afternoon'],
   ['morning']
];

let checker = (arr, str) => arr.every(a => a.includes(str));

console.log(checker(data, 'morning'));
console.log(checker(data, 'afternoon'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
let arr = [['morning', 'afternoon'],['morning'],['morning', 'afternoon'],['morning', 'afternoon'],['morning']];

console.log(arr.every(v => v.includes('morning'))); // true
console.log(arr.every(v => v.includes('afternoon'))); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use .every()

 array.every(d => d.includes("morning")) // true
 array.every(d => d.includes("afternoon")) //false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and coerces to `boolean` the result of [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) which returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

Code:

```js
const data = [['morning', 'afternoon'],['morning'],['morning', 'afternoon'],['morning','afternoon'],['morning']];
const checker = (arr, str) => arr.every(a => !!a.find(a => str === a));

console.log(checker(data, 'morning'));
console.log(checker(data, 'afternoon'));
```